# How to avoid a thick line in the linear-gradient between two colors

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, linear-gradients

```js
function init_anim_imgs() {

   let delay = 0

    delay += 2000
    setTimeout(() => {
         document.getElementById("background").classList.add('second')

    },delay)

    delay += 2000
    setTimeout(() => {
         document.getElementById("background").classList.add('second')

    },delay)


    delay += 2000
    setTimeout(() => {
         document.getElementById("background").classList.add('third')

    },delay)

}

window.onload = init_anim_imgs();
```

```css
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
}

#ad {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    height: 600px;
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid black;
    /* background-color: #041e42; */
}

#banner {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;

}


#background {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 1800px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #041e42 0%, #041e42 33.33%, #041e42 33.33%, #008ba6 66.66%, #008ba6 66.66%, #008ba6 100%);
    /* background: linear-gradient(#041e42 30%, 50%, #008ba6 90%); */
    /* background:
        linear-gradient(#041e42, #041e42) 0 0 / 100% 600px,
        linear-gradient(#041e42, #008ba6) 0 600px / 100% 600px,
        linear-gradient(#008ba6, #008ba6) 0 1200px / 100% 600px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; */
    transform: translate3d(0, -1200px, 0);
    transition: transform 2s ease-in;
}


#background.second {
    transform: translate3d(0, -600px, 0);
}


#background.third {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://secure-ds.serving-sys.com/BurstingScript/adKit/adkit.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=300, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="ad.size" content="width=300,height=600">
    <title> 300x600</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="ad">

        <div id="background" class=""></div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hello and thanks for your help! I need to create a gradient between two colors for an animated banner. The dimensions of the  element are 300x1800px. The concept is to have the first third of the banner in a single color, apply a linear-gradient for the second third, and use the other color for the final third. The goal is to animate the banner so that each third changes in each of the 3 frames (300x600px)

However, I'm facing an issue where two thick lines appear between the divisions, and I'm unsure how to prevent this. I've attempted various approaches, as you can see in the commented code, but I haven't been able to resolve the problem. Here's the code:

CSS:

````
#background {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 1800px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #041e42 0%, #041e42 33.33%, #041e42 33.33%, #008ba6 66.66%, #008ba6 66.66%, #008ba6 100%);
    /* background: linear-gradient(#041e42 30%, 50%, #008ba6 90%); */
    /* background:
        linear-gradient(#041e42, #041e42) 0 0 / 100% 600px,
        linear-gradient(#041e42, #008ba6) 0 600px / 100% 600px,
        linear-gradient(#008ba6, #008ba6) 0 1200px / 100% 600px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; */
    transform: translate3d(0, -1200px, 0);
    transition: transform 2s ease-in;
}


#background.second {
    transform: translate3d(0, -600px, 0);
}


#background.third {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}```


JS:
````

function init_anim_imgs() {

```
delay = 0

delay += 2000
setTimeout(() => {
     document.getElementById("background").classList.add('second')

},delay)

delay += 2000
setTimeout(() => {
     document.getElementById("background").classList.add('second')

},delay)


delay += 2000
setTimeout(() => {
     document.getElementById("background").classList.add('third')

},delay)
```

}```